# Understanding how Transcrypt autotests document the code

Tags: python, transcrypt

The autotests are an integral part of the documentation of Transcrypt. However I am struggling to understand how they reveal expected behavior.  For example in:
[https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/blob/master/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/transcrypt/proxies/**init**.py](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/blob/master/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/transcrypt/proxies/__init__.py)

I can't really tell what are the right/expected answers.  How does one interpret tests like the following?

```
autoTester.check (b.p, b.q, b.r, b.s)
b.p = 4
b.r = 5
autoTester.check (b.p, b.q, b.r, b.s)
```

Answer (score 3):

The autotests are run both under CPython and Transcrypt. The outcomes are automatically verified to be identical when loading the result into your browser. This is known as "back to back testing" and it is what the calls to the `check`function do. So correct behaviour for Transcrypt is simply ("operationally") defined as just CPython behavior. Python, like most scripting languages, lacks a formal semantics specification.

Transcrypt supports some 95% of CPython. The internals of Transcrypt, being a Python to JavaScript compiler, are quite different. This especially holds for the so called "magic methods" of CPython (the ones starting and ending with __), although, e.g. for operator overloading, many of them are supported by Transcrypt as well.  All features that are in autotests are supported with identical behavior, so together they lay down "what  you can do" in Transcrypt.

You can run the autotests yourself as follows, e.g. for the Transcrypt basic tests:

- Go to folder .../development/automated_tests/transcrypt in your Transcrypt installation
- At the command prompt type: transcrypt -r -c -da autotest.py
- After that, at the command prompt type: transcrypt -c -da autotest.py
- Open the generated file autotest.html in your browser

Click on the blue (or, not to be hoped, red) lines to see the outcome of the code to be compared. It should be unsurprising: All that the autotests do is indeed confirming Transcrypt behaviour on them is just CPython behaviour.

*Autotest results for "Hello world" with deliberate error:*

[image: Autotest results for "Hello world" with deliberate error]

*Transcrypt's basic features autotest results:*

[image: Transcrypt's basic featurs autotest results]

The value of the autotests is twofold:

- Whenever a feature is added to Transcrypt, they make it easy to assure nothing has fallen over (regression test)
- Reading throught the source of the autotests will give a good impression of which features are supported.

Of course a test like

```
autoTester.check (b.p, b.q, b.r, b.s)
b.p = 4
b.r = 5
autoTester.check (b.p, b.q, b.r, b.s)
```

, although required for complete coverage, is quite trivial. However e.g. operator overloading code like

```
def __matmul__ (self, other):
    result = Matrix (self.nRows, other.nCols)
    for iTargetRow in range (result.nRows):
        for iTargetCol in range (result.nCols):
            for iTerm in range (self.nCols):
                result._ [iTargetRow][iTargetCol] += self._ [iTargetRow][iTerm] * other._ [iTerm][iTargetCol]
    return result
```

isn't.

Code for library packages can also be autotested, and with complicated mathematical algorithms, e.g. the 2D FFT (transforming a image to a frequency array using complex numbers, part of [Numscrypt](https://github.com/QQuick/Numscrypt)) this is a necessity, to keep code like

```
__pragma__ ('opov')

orig2 = num.zeros ((128, 128), 'complex128')
orig2 [32 : 96, 32 : 96] = num.ones ((64, 64), 'complex128')

autoTester.check ('Original samples', num.round (orig2 + delta, 3) [64 : 68, 16 : 112] .tolist (), '<br>')

if transpiled:
    timeStartFft = getNow ()

freqs2 = fft.fft2 (orig2)
if transpiled:
    timeStopFft = getNow () 

autoTester.check ('Frequencies', num.round (freqs2 + delta, 3)  [64 : 68, 16 : 112] .tolist (), '<br>')

if transpiled:
    timeStartIfft = getNow ()
reconstr2 = fft.ifft2 (freqs2)
if transpiled:
    timeStopIfft = getNow ()    

if transpiled:
    print ('FFT2 for {} samples took {} ms'.format (orig2.size, timeStopFft - timeStartFft))
    print ('IFFT2 for {} samples took {} ms'.format (orig2.size, timeStopIfft - timeStartIfft))

autoTester.check ('Reconstructed samples', num.round (reconstr2 + delta, 3)  [64 : 68, 16 : 112] .tolist (), '<br>')

__pragma__ ('noopov')
```

from breaking. So whenever someone contributes to Transcrypt, he/she is encouraged to include an autotest. A good example of this is the regular expression module, which came with a fair amount of autotests.

Note that the autotests will hardly help you learn Python as such. There are many tutorials and books on that, e.g. "Python in a Nutshell" by Alex Martelli, Anna Ravenscroft and Steve Holden.

Some more info on the inner workings of Transcrypts autotest facility is found here:

http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/autotesting_transcrypt.html